# How to show output (debug) window during execution?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to write my project and want to use the output window  (Re: debug) during the execution of my program. Currently, whenever I begin execution of my program the output window is replaced by diagnostics (which I would also like to see), is there any way I can enable the output window permanently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of tool windows displayed is independent for while running the debugger and not.  While running your project, you can open the Output window from the View menu and it will be open for future sessions too.

Comment: Okay, so I've got the window displaying now, and now I can't see any output in the window. I've got it set to show output from debug, I'm using the Debug solution configuration, and I'm using Debug.WriteLine(string) to print out the information yet nothing is showing. Any ideas why this may be? note: previously I was able to see output in the output window just after the program finished execution, this is not the case now.

Comment: Try Debug.Print() instead

Comment: You should open the IDE options dialogue and look under the Debugging section and make sure you have things configured correctly, e.g. make sure debugging output is not redirected to the Immediate window.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was output was redirected to the immediate window, also in regards to @CruleD's comment, print, write and writeline all work.